# django south - column none does not exist

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

i am failing to migrate using south. the problem is this:

i created a model, then i did schemamigration app --auto, then migrate app, it was fine. then later on, i added another field to this model and then did again those two commands, but now it is saying, column 'None' doesnot exist. i think, it was because i had a foreignkey field and that didnot have default value, i added some empty string default value, then did the commands again, it said the same error, now i deleted the model and did schemamigration and migrate app, but it still keeps giving this error.

this is my model:

```
class User(models.Model):
  registerdate = models.CharField(max_length=400,default='')
  vorname = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
  nachname = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,default='')
  strasse = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
  hausnr = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
  stadt = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
  land = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
  ##for confirm mails - the hash 
  unique = models.CharField(max_length=400,default='')

  kennwort = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='')
  username = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='')

  locations = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
```

can someone please help me?

thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please update question with error Traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
field_name = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit your migration file, or regenerate it with a valid default. Your assumption of the invalid default is correct.